# Virtualmin - How to use reserved email names? (domains@example.com)

Tags: email

I'm in the process of transferring a clients mail service from cPanel to Virtualmin. This person has multiple email addresses on different domains. Everything is working fine except today I am transferring the last of his email accounts which is `domains@example.com` but Virtualmin is giving me the following error:

```
Failed to save mailbox : The username domains is reserved for use by Virtualmin
```

I've tried asking the client if he would just switch this email address to something different (such as domain without the "s") but the problem is that the `domains@example.com`email address is used as the registration email for all of his business contacts regarding domains and DNS such as registrars.

The main issue is that this is the domain he uses in all SOA records for more then 1000 separate domains. He is very adamant to keep the "domains" email address and for sure would not like to have to edit over 1000 zonefiles to update the SOA email.

Is there any way to get Virtualmin to release the lock on this email address? It is my understanding that Virtualmin reserves the `logs@`, `virtualmin-backup@`, and `domains@` addresses.

Im open to any sort of work around even hard coded edits to get this working.

Comment: I would like to help, but in this particular case, you might need to contact virtualmin team. It look a lot like a soft specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use a `email alias` in this case.

The reason is that `domains`, `Logs`, and `virtualmin-backup` are the names of sub-directories that Virtualmin creates under each domain's home, so allowing a username with the same name would cause them to clash.

A work-around for this is to create an email alias for `domains@example.com` (on Mail Aliases page) that forwards to the actual mailbox with a different name.

However there is currently a bug in Virtualmin that still won't allow you to use these names as mail aliases - This is a bug as it should be possible to have an alias named `domains` (or the other reserved names).

```
Failed to save alias : Missing or invalid alias name (no @ should be included)
```

This should be fixed in an upcoming release.

Source - https://www.virtualmin.com/node/40377